# Cannot set tab bar items text programmatically on tabBarControllerVC

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller that has storyboard references linking the appropriate storyboard.
I am having trouble localizing the tab bar titles.
Currently the tab bar titles are set on the storyboard only. 
When I clear the titles for the tab bar items in the story board and attempt to set them in code below.

```
mainTabBar.items![0].title = NSLocalizedString("mainTabBar_tab0", comment: "")
mainTabBar.items![1].title = NSLocalizedString("mainTabBar_tab1", comment: "")
mainTabBar.items![2].title = NSLocalizedString("mainTabBar_tab2", comment: "")
mainTabBar.items![3].title = NSLocalizedString("mainTabBar_tab3", comment: "")
mainTabBar.items![4].title = NSLocalizedString("mainTabBar_tab4", comment: "")
```

This yields inconclusive results and the tab bar items remain blank.

Below is a screenshot of how I have my tab bar items established.

[image]

EDIT---Adding Localized Files

```
"mainTabBar_tab0" = "AA";
"mainTabBar_tab1" = "BB";
"mainTabBar_tab2" = "CC";
"mainTabBar_tab3" = "DD";
"mainTabBar_tab4" = "EE";
```

I am calling the tabBar items title code inside the main tab bar controller as shown in picture.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your localized strings file?  It's possible your keys aren't matching, so you get back empty strings.

Comment: Also, where are you calling this code?

Comment: Check update for your answers @kid_x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try setting each ViewController title in their corresponding viewWillAppear? Something like this:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].title = NSLocalizedString("mainTabBar_tab0", comment: "comment")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Wow awesome! Super simple! Thanks for the help :) I never tried this ! Its interesting how setting the code on the main tab bar controller does not set the titles.